# gevent-websocket python WAMP client?

Tags: python, websocket, gevent, wamp-protocol

I'm using gevent-websocket to write an WAMP server, which supports rpc and pubsub nicely.

But is there any help in gevent-websocket to write a WAMP client?

I know there is autobahn, but its API and size is the reason that I use gevent-websocket instead.

So in general, the question is: is there any easy way to write a python WAMP client without using autobahn?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with AutobahnPython's "API and size"?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jgelens/gevent-websocket/tree/master/examples/wamp

```
from geventwebsocket.protocols.wamp import WampProtocol, export_rpc
```

There is a whole example of WAMP in the gevent-websocket github.